Remove prepending character from block of lines in bash
I have a text file that has at some point a text like this:
[....previous text...]

#[ID1]
#my_url="http://miccheck12.com"
#your_url="http://miccheck12.com"
#comments=""

[....subsequent text...]

The block of text I'm interested in is identified by ID1. For all the block I want to remove the prepending character #.
I was trying to do this with sed. Given that for example sed -i 's/#\[ID1\]/\[ID1\]/g' file.txt  works successfully, I've tried to extend this to the next line like: sed -i 's/#\[ID1\]\n#my_url/\[ID1\]/g' file.txt but it's not catching the lines anymore. How can I solve this? I'm not even sure sed is the best approach.

The reason why it does not catch the lines is the \n, sed works only on single lines. It would need some more complicated sed code but I think it can be done.  You would need to read...

Try:
sed '/#\[ID1\]/,/^$/s/^#//'

Between the lines #\[ID1\] and an empty line, remove the leading #.

Hi Can you it works but it's a little obscure: ^# means that it starts with # but what about the rest?

What about the rest? Check https://regex101.com/ , https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Range-Addresses . Maybe the regex is too exact, edited.

You second sed script can work unchanged with perl :
perl -0777 -pe 's/#\[ID1\]\n#my_url/\[ID1\]/g' input.txt

Once you tested, you can change input.txt with :
perl -i -0777 -pe 's/#\[ID1\]\n#my_url/\[ID1\]/g' input.txt


This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed '/^#\[ID1\]$/{:a;s/^#//;n;/^\[.*\]$/!ba}' file

If a line begins and ends #[ID1], then:

Remove the leading #
Print the current line and fetch the next
If that line does not begin and [...], repeat as above.

An alternative solution:
sed '/\[.*\]$/h;G;/\[ID1\]/s/^#//;P;d' file

